# Rewind posts then show only first post

Tags: wp-query

Is there a way to run the loop as usual (showing all the posts), rewind the posts and then do a secondary loop (if one is actually needed) to show only the first post in an archive template?

My requirement is to setup a template which generates a list of all the current category's posts in a sidebar and then show only the first post in the main content area.

Something along these lines:

```
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <?php rewind_posts() ?>
            <div class="maincontent">
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_content() ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There if few ways to achieve what you need:

#### Option 1:

Add `break` after `the_content()` in the main content loop.

#### Option 2:

You can do something like this but I don't think so that it is a good solution.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
    $first_post = true;
    ?>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                    if ( $first_post ) {
                        $first_post_content = get_the_content();
                        $first_post = false;
                    }
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php rewind_posts() ?>
    <div class="maincontent">
        <?php echo $first_post_content; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

#### Option 3:

Second query. In my opinion the best solution.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php rewind_posts() ?>
    <div class="maincontent">
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ) ?>
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: BTW the proper solution of this problem is to display all posts in the sidebar using WP_Query and then modify main query using pre_get_posts filter for this specific archive.